# How to access these tables more efficiently in django

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

we have the following data base schema to store different types of data.

- DataDefinition: basic information about the new data.
- *FieldDefinition: Every DataDefinition has some fields. Every field has a type, title, etc, that information is stored here. Every DataDefinition has more than one *FieldDefinition associated. I have put '*' because we have a lot of different models, one for every kind of field supported.
- DataValue, *FieldValues: we store the definition and the values in different models.

With this setup, to retrieve a data from our database we need to do a lot of queries:

1. Retrieve the DataDefinition.
2. Retrieve the DataValue.
3. Retrieve the *FieldDefinition associated to that DataDefinition.
4. Retrieve all the *FieldValues associated to those *FieldDefinition.

So, if n is the average number of fields of a DataDefinition, we need to make 2*n+2 queries to the database to retrieve a single value.

We cannot change this setup, but queries are quite slow. So to speed it up I have thought the following: store a joined version of the tables. I do not know if this is possible but I cannot think of any other way. Any suggestion?

Update: we are already using `prefetch_related` and `select_related` and it's still slow.

Use Case Right now: get an entire data object from the one object value:

```
someValue = SomeTypeValue.objects.filter(value=value).select_related('DataValue', 'DataDefinition')[0]

# for each *FieldDefinition/*FieldValue model

definition = SomeFieldDefinition.objects.filter(*field_definition__id=someValue.data_value.data_definition.id)


value = SomeFieldValue.objects.filter(*field_definition__id=definition.id)
```

And with that info you can now build the entire data object.

`Django: 1.11.20`
`Python: 2.7`

Comment: You can work with [**`.select_related(..)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [**`.prefetch_related(..)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to fetch relevant items in bulk.

Comment: We are already using that...

Comment: @AntonioGamizDelgado show this view that makes these queries and your usage of `select_related` and `prefetch_related`

Comment: I have added what I have more or less.

Comment: My main is problem is that I can follow these foreign keys: FieldValue -> DataValue -> DataDefinition. But from DataDefinition I cannot use select_related to retrieve the other values nor their  definitions.